# Kafka Consumer on Flutter Client Changing the Host IP

Tags: flutter, apache-kafka

I'm using this package (kafkabr: ^1.0.2) to build consumer in my flutter app, but when i run the app, i get an exception that the app. couldn't not connect to the host. the strange thing is the IP mentioned in the exception is different than the one i gave to the host object.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka will return `advertised.listeners` defined in the broker properties for post-bootstrap client connections. You need to verify that those values are *also* reachable from all clients.

Also Kafka clients shouldn't be used from a mobile application for the above reason that addresses can change, and must preserve a constant connection stream; instead, you can use a Kafka REST Proxy and standard HTTP libraries in Flutter to interact with that.